# C# Time elapsed with Server and Client

Tags: c#, time, timer, client-server

I want to synchronize time between server and client.

The purpose of this thing is I build an internet cafe application. I want to implement function that can recovery if server or client down. For example, if server down while client time elapsed isn't stop, then after server comeback online again so server will sync time between client and start with the same time.

What is the algorithm that I should use ?

[image: Server-Client]

Comment: How accurate do you need this to be, and how much network latency do you expect between client and server?

Comment: Do you want to sync the whole system or only your application?

Comment: maybe the purpose of this should be explained too... why do you want server and client to be synchronized?

Comment: @Andreas, only my application.

Comment: @AtomSkaaskaHic how do you connect the client and the server?

Comment: You seem to be saying that time synchronisation is important to handling a recovery. Perhaps we need more information on why.

Comment: @RobSmyth, because it has travel time between two computer. So If server, use serverTimer.start() and then send command to client for trigger clientTimer.start(). It will produce some delay for sure.